# \usepackage{colorspace} package doesn't work with \usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}

Tags: color

The `xcolor` package has a nice feature where you can specify a colour in multiple colour models. The appropriate colour is then picked depending on the options `xcolor` is loaded with.

e.g., I can define [PANTONE 7740 CP](https://www.pantone.com/color-finder/7740-CP) in a colour palette file as:

```
\definecolor{PANTONE-7740-CP}{RGB/cmyk}{70,151,58/0.75,0,0.95,0.15}
```

then depending on whether I load `xcolor` with the `rgb` option or the `cmyk` option, I'll get the appropriate colour space.

Now, let's say I want to work in CMYK and also specify a spot colour or registration colour. e.g., I can define the special registration colour space using the `colorspace` package:

```
\usepackage{colorspace}
\definespotcolor{registration}{All}{1,1,1,1}
```

However, if I load `xcolor` with the `cmyk` option, I get errors when trying to use this registration colour.

```
! Argument of \c@lor@@cmyk has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.9 \textcolor{registration}{Registration colour}
```

If just let `colorspace` load `xcolor` then the RGB definitions from my colour palette are picked up instead of the CMYK ones, which obviously isn't what I want.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

## MWE

In this MWE, my test colour is RGB red and CMYK cyan, so you easily see which colour is in use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colorspace}
\definecolor{testcolour}{RGB/cmyk}{255,0,0/1,0,0,0}
\definespotcolor{registration}{All}{1,1,1,1}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{testcolour}{Test Colour}

\textcolor{registration}{Registration colour}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There seems to be a bug, but I have no idea, where. I suggest to write to the maintainer of the colorspace package first.

Comment: I have submitted a bug report at https://github.com/jbezos/colorspace/issues/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suitable workaround in my case is to call `\selectcolormodel{natural}` before setting the colour to a spot colour:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colorspace}
\definecolor{testcolour}{RGB/cmyk}{255,0,0/1,0,0,0}
\selectcolormodel{natural}
\definespotcolor{registration}{All}{1,1,1,1}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{testcolour}{Test Colour}

{\selectcolormodel{natural}\textcolor{registration}{Registration colour}}

\textcolor{testcolour}{Test Colour}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the package option `cmyk` calls `\selectcolormodel`, which, as explained in the manual, doesn't work yet. This is a limitation, which means `cmyk` must be selected explicitly when defining colors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is this something you might implement in the foreseeable future?

Comment: The Unicode bidi algorithm is driving me crazy, you know (there are still some issues, even when the Unicode tests passed :-( ), and this is my priority. Perhaps by the end of year.

Comment: are there any pitfalls with my workaround I posted as an answer?